# I need to fix my sub menu bar. It cant dropdown properly

Tags: css, megamenu

My sub menu is a mess. Can you guys help me to fix it? I do many time in css but it is not working. This is my menu link. I'm not good in css because I am new to css :

[image]

```
#megaMenu #megaST .no-megamenu .menu-row.sub-menu-0 {
top: 44px;
left: 0px !important;
}

#megaMenu #megaST .no-megamenu .menu-row.sub-menu-0 li {
width: auto;
float: none;
position: relative;
}

#megaMenu #megaST .no-megamenu .menu-row.sub-menu-0 li.item-parent:after {
content: '\e879';
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 10px;
font-family: "fontello";
}
```

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be great, if not then share your HTML too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is small width(74px) has been assigned for your `col1` div. Add the following class in your css.

```
div.nav-dd.col1
{
 width:auto !important;
}
```